# Movie converted into animated Gif banner is slow loading

Tags: gif, animated-gif

Hi all why is my gif image banner appears so slow compared to the gif banner of PayPal and AirBnb websites. They load without delay.

Besides, my gif is blur because they are in low resolution, while the gif banner on PayPal and AirBnB are very clear.

I converted my video, which is 25 seconds long into the gif image. Set the framerate to 15 and in low resolution.

Is it slow because my video is too long? Is it because there are too many movements in the video?

How do I create clear gif images that loads immediately on my webpage?

Comment: What is the filesize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...the gif banner of PayPal and AirBnb websites. They load without delay.

PayPal and Airbnb don't use animated GIF banners. They use streaming media (MP4). And likely use a static overlay until the media is ready, to minimise any apparent delay at the start.

> ... 25 seconds long into the gif image.

Animated GIFs, by comparison, are hopelessly inefficient and do not stream (very well). A 25 second (full banner width) GIF animation is likely to be very large and will probably only play smoothly once it has downloaded in its entirety.